# Number of item in cart at theme level

Tags: 7, theming, commerce

I have to display number of item in cart/basket in design where I can't use the menu. So my question is...how to access number of item of cart at theme level?

Is there any function for template file which can return me this, so that I can show it in page.tpl.php ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`commerce_cart_order_load()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_order_load/7) to load the order for the current user, and an [`EntityMetadataWrapper`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.wrapper.inc/class/EntityMetadataWrapper/7) to extract the relevant field data, and [`commerce_line_items_quantity()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!line_item!commerce_line_item.module/function/commerce_line_items_quantity/7) to get at the actual quantities. e.g.

```
if ($order = commerce_cart_order_load($GLOBALS['user']->uid)) {
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  $quantity = commerce_line_items_quantity($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items);

  // Do something with $quantity...
}
```

This code can be used in a module or theme.

Comment: You took no time in responding & it works like charm...Thanks :)

Comment: You can also check out the implementation in commerce_cart_menu_item_title().